# Use boost thread_pool with boost steady_timer

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I want to use execute a timer-based task with a pool of threads. I wrote the following code:

```
boost::asio::thread_pool thread_pool{};
boost::asio::steady_timer timer{thread_pool.get_executor(), std::chrono::seconds{1}};

timer.async_wait([](const boost::system::error_code&){
     std::cout << "Task Completed" << std::endl;
});
```

Is this the correct way to achieve this? or should I be using an `io_context` and then run that in every thread of `thread_group`? From what I can find online is that `io_context` should be used for any io including timer-related tasks but then why does the above code compile with `thread_pool`? Since one can argue that using thread_pool provides a cleaner outlook is there any place I should use `io_context`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this the correct way to achieve this?

It is one correct way that can work

> or should I be using an io_context and then run that in every thread
> of thread_group?

You should not. Basically for the reason that it is almost *exactly* the same thing, but less correct. With your own thread-groups you have to do work to maintain fair scheduling and handle exceptions correctly.

> Since one can argue that using thread_pool provides a cleaner outlook is there any place I should use io_context?

Good point actually. You should use `io_context` when you don't want threads. Sometimes your platform doesn't support thread creation, thread scheduling introduces non-determinism you want to avoid, or you just don't want to have any synchronization issues even regarding globals. E.g.

```
int main() {
   io_context ioc(1);
   start_server(ioc);
   ioc.run(); // main thread
}
```

Is conceptually similar to

```
int main() {
   thread_pool ioc(1);
   start_server(ioc);
   ioc.join(); // separate thread
}
```

I liberally write the latter, also because it can reduce the need for work-guards (`thread_pool` hold an executor work guard internally).